# Stackless installation and configuration with DJango

Tags: django, stackless, python-stackless

I am trying to run a DJango Command Extension which uses stackless.

I have installed Stackless Python (compiled with python 2.5) so whenever I type python2.5 at the console it fires up indicating that the version is 
**Python 2.5.2 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (python-2.52:72942, May 26 2009, 23:07:34) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2**

But in my eclipse I have configured my django application to run with python2.6. Specifically in the PyDev settings. So obviously when I mention **import stackless** it says that there is no such package.

The problem is even if I add the '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages' directory it does not import stackless.

What is the solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to point eclipse at your 2.5 stackless installation unless you have a very good reason to use 2.6 over 2.5?

...or recompile for 2.6 and add it to your 2.6 installation.

Comment: I recompiled it with python2.6. I also added the /usr/local/bin/python2.6 in the eclipse pydev config. However if i attempt to use that config in eclipse and run shell or runserver it says that psycopg2 is installed but there is some UCS4 encoding error. But it was working fine in the original python2.6 config.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose  Window->preferencess in eclipse menu
2. pydev->interpeter-Python
3. choose tab forsed biltins
4. press new, type "stackless"